# Ruby Rails STI Controllers and test unit routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, sti

I am using STI on my ruby on rails project and I am trying to create tests for controllers.

Example:

```
class Animal
end

class Lion < Animal
end
```

The specific is that i am trying to disable Animal routes completly ( except index ), so i can only use routes that specify the type. The Lion object routes point to Animal controller with type specified.

In runtime it works, but testing it doesnt : If i create a lion_controller_test, it tells me that lion_controller_test doesnt exist.

If i try to do it on animal_controller_test , it tells me routes doesnt exit ( although using a fixture object that has a type configured ).

How can i do :

```
get :show, id: @my_lion.id
```

and it detect the proper STI route ?

Also, should i really be disabling all "generic Animal routes" except index ? isnt it safer to do this for STI ?

Thanks

EDIT:

routes :

```
resources :animals, only: [:index] ( only index, i dont want resources create/edit/show/destroy without specifing type ) 

resources :lions, controller: 'animal', type: 'Lion'
```

test ( test-unit rails )

test/controllers/animals_controller_test.rb

if i create a test/controllers/lions_controller_test.rb, it complains that lions_controller does not exist ( quite right :) )

EDIT: Reply to "elements"

Well, the issue here is that i am only enabling animal_controller index route. All others i would want to disable and only enable them throught lion routes ( that forward to controller 'animal' ).

When using STI, does everybody enable all routes of the base sti model ( animal ) as also the lion routes ?

Is it bad or impossible to disable the routes of the base sti model ?

Comment: Please add your routes and the spec path and filename

Comment: What does `rake routes` give you for animal and lion related routes?  Which route are you getting the 'doesn't exist' error for in your animal controller test?